# Obtain results from a specific column different from each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT MessageID 
FROM ReadHistory 
WHERE EmployeeNumber = '2230' AND Response <> 'Hang-up' 
GROUP BY MessageID
```

This is my first script that was working and I was getting these results:

| MessageID |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 11 |
| 14 |
| 16 |
| 17 |

Now that we are making changes I need to get the results sorted and with more columns, but the script is triggered. this is my script.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MessageID, ID, TTCallLogId, TTHourID 
FROM dbo.tblTTP_Messages_ReadHistory 
WHERE EmployeeNumber = '2230' AND Response <> 'Hang-up'
GROUP BY MessageID, ID, TTCallLogId, TTHourID 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Results:

| ID | MessageID | TTCallLogId | TTHourID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 241 | 14 | NULL | NULL |
| 240 | 14 | NULL | NULL |
| 239 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 238 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 237 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 236 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 235 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 234 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 233 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 232 | 16 | NULL | NULL |
| 231 | 16 | NULL | NULL |

etc.

QUESTION:

I want to get only 5 first results as in the first script, but I take into account the other fields, and that this order, how can I do that?

Comment: We'd need to see your starting data in order to be able to assist. I suggest posting as DDL+DML so we can play with it.

Comment: What is your criteria for selecting/filtering the additional rows?

Comment: @sTTu well in this case my selection criteria is the user and to obtain the last record.

Comment: The 2 columns all NULL doesn't seem to add any value, ignoring those why could you not just use `max(ID)` and `group by MessageID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the last row (i.e. the row with the highest ID) per MessageID. If this is so, use a window function, e.g. `MAX OVER`:

```
select messageid, ttcalllogid, tthourid
from
(
  select
    messageid, ttcalllogid, tthourid, id, 
    max(id) over (partition by messageid) as last_id_for_message
  from readhistory 
  where employeenumber = 2230 and response <> 'Hang-up' 
) marked
where id = last_id_for_message;
```